# How to get a mock repository into a model object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am creating some unit tests for a Country model object. This is partly-generated by the Linq-to-SQL mechanism from a database table and partly under my control. This class uses the CountryRepository for some checks when checking it is valid; particularly that a country of this name doesn't already exist in the database.

As one ought not to embroil oneself in the database during unit tests, I created a mock repository to provide pretend data, and modify the model class like this:-

```
public partial class Country
{
    private ICountryRepository country_repository;

    public Country(ICountryRepository passed_country_repository)
    {
        country_repository = passed_country_repository;
    }

    //...etc
```

I can then construct this object in the test like this:-

```
Country test_country = new Country(new MockCountryRepository())
                       {
                            // code in here
                       };
```

and the tests run satisfactorily.

The problem comes in actual live usage; I have to prefix every usage of the repository with this:-

```
if (country_repository == null)
{
    country_repository = new CountryRepository();
}
```

as the `country_repository` variable is unset if the zero-parameter constructor is invoked. I originally had the declaration line reading:-

```
private ICountryRepository country_repository = new CountryRepository();
```

but that attempts a database connection whichever constructor is used. I can't change the zero-parameter constructor to set `country_repository` to anything because it is automatically-generated and my changes might disappear at zero notice.

Is there a better way of getting the MockCountryRepository into the model object? Or have I missed the point here somewhere, and if so, what should I be doing?

Comment: Are you using a DI container? Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. It is unclear why a model would need to have external dependencies injected.

Comment: @Nkosi, yes, I believe so (I'm by no means an expert at this). I have the classes `CountryRepository` and `MockCountryRepository` both implementing `ICountryRepository`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I get that you are injecting abstractions. What I do not get is why a model would need to have dependencies. Seems like a code smell and a violation of single responsibility principle. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I agree with @Nkosi's comment about not having repository inside the model class. However, if you can't refactor it for whatever reason, you can use [write-only properties](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/write-only-property-in-c-sharp) to set repository on your model

Comment: @Nkosi, righto. I'll ask for help about the original problem. Thanks.